После нажатия кнопки "зарегестрировался" бот не выполняет функции дальше
import telebot
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

if random.random() < 0.85:
    random_number = round(random.uniform(0.01, 10.45), 2)
else:
    random_number = round(random.uniform(10.46, 55.23), 2)

print(random_number)

bot = telebot.TeleBot("")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row(InlineKeyboardButton("Регистрация", url=""))

    markup.row(InlineKeyboardButton("Зарегестрировался", callback_data='reg_user'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f"Перед началом зарегестрируйся нажав кнопку Регистрация, после вернись в бота и нажми кнопку Зарегестрировался", parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    new_datetime = current_datetime + timedelta(minutes=3)
    new_datetime_str = new_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if call.data == "reg_user":
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.row(InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='nextkef'))
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="",
                              reply_markup=markup)

    elif call.data == "next":
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.row(InlineKeyboardButton("", callback_data='next'))

        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text=f"", reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling()

